# How I can capture all output of my application?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm writing a C++ application and I want to capture all application output (asserts, exceptions, segfaults) into text file and console at the same time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `tee` command:

```
$ /path/to/myapp 2>&1 | tee /path/to/file.log
```

Comment: You should redirect the stderr to stdout as well for this to work as intended: /path/to/myapp 2>&1 | tee /path/to/file.log    
TL;DR: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: @CaioOliveira you're right - I saw output and immediately mentally jumped to "stdout". Edited and fixed. Thanks!

Comment: It's work for asserts and exceptions but I don't see message about segfault or other Linux signals.

Answer (score 1):

use the dup2 function to redirect the stdout_fileno, example:

```
fd = open(filename, O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY, 0755);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Comment: I want output to file and console at the same time. Your solution grab output from console to file.